# How to use Haskell higher order function foldr to calculate length of a string

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions

I want use Haskell higher order function Foldr to calculate the length of a string

```
stringlength = foldr (\_n -> 1 + n) 0
```

it give following error.what is the problem with this code?

```
Unresolved top-level overloading
*** Binding             : stringlength
*** Outstanding context : (Num b, Num (b -> b))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, hugs seems pretty much dead, the last release was over five years ago. The language has evolved since then, so I recommend using a more up-to-date implementation. The standard implementation is [GHC](http://haskell.org/ghc), which includes a compiler and an interpreter.

Comment: I misread the question but wound up making this implementation that uses no lambda expressions: `stringlength = foldr (const (+1)) 0`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add a space to your pattern matching

```
(\_ n -> ... )
   ^^here
```

currently you are matching against a single variable `_n` instead of against `_` and `n`, as you probably want to.

Comment: thanks.can you please explain this code?how this calculate the length? foldr (\_ n -> 1 + n) 0

Comment: @user1150071: If I were you I would try to get at the definition of foldr (use hoogle for that) and then run it step by step on paper. I don't think I would be able to explain better then that.